# Is there an easy way to flatten meshes/surfaces and then UV map them onto an image?

Tags: mesh, uv

I am new to blender and using it to render models of custom vehicle wraps but am running into some problems. I used UV mapping to get the design onto the model but it is far from perfect. I have a template of flattened vinyl pieces that I want to mask to specific surfaces. I organized the model so that the surface shapes that I want are a separate layer and then tried the UV mapping however, the only way my surfaces will map in one piece is if I use project from view and I don't understand why the mesh for each surface gets split up otherwise. Is there an easy fix to this so I can get the correct shape and coverage without warping the wrap on the model?

Here are some screenshots: one is project from view and kept the mesh together, the other is using uv unwrap which made the mesh split up into multiple pieces. Also, I adjusted the vertices on the mesh projected from view to get the correct shape but that seems to distort the graphics when projected to the model.

I basically just want to flatten the meshes as whole parts and then just scale them to the correct size for that template.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please include a screenshot image or two that better demonstrates what you're trying to achieve, and the problems you're having...